# Dummy Printer Device Context

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

I am trying to work on something that captures the screen of a window, but it doesn't work on windows that are launched in an SSH session. Is there anyway to make the remote applications print contents to a dummy display/printer so that a gui is capturable? Thanks!

*I am using PrintWindow to capture the image now*

William

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [CreateEnhMetaFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183498%28v=vs.85%29) might be helpful here as a HDC - `HDC deviceContext = CreateEnhMetaFile(NULL, NULL, size, NULL)`, followed by your code to do `PrintWindow`.  Does this work in your SSH session?